# Update TimeStamps in "normal" Table in a Temp-Table scenario

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

In a table that use system versioning aka Temporal tables, is there a way to modify the time stamp columns (row start, row end, often named ValidFrom and ValidTo) some how?

It can be done in the temporal table itself when system versioning is off and the timestamps updates comply to the row-end-of-previuos-must-equal-row-start-of-next-pattern.

But it doesn't seems to work for the "normal" table itself, even if system versioning is off.

This works for the TT:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Customer] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
update [dbo].[CustomerHistory] set ValidFrom = '2024-03-25 11:21:38.1854297'  where [Id] = 5
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Customer] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

But it fails for the "normal" table

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Customer] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
update [dbo].[Customer] set ValidFrom = '2024-03-25 11:21:38.1854297'  where [Id] = 5
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Customer] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON);
```

producing the error message: "The GENERATED ALWAYS columns in the "dbo.Customer" table cannot be updated."

Any way to get around it?

I need to copy a bunch of tables 1:1 from one DB to another, and the TimeStamps of the TT / History Tables need to be the ones from the original source database tables...

Comment: *"But it fails for the "normal" table"* What does, "it fails" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? A system crash? Something else entirely?

Comment: @ThomA if get an error msg like (translated): "The GENERATED ALWAYS columns in the "dbo.Customer" table cannot be updated." Though Versioning has been deactivated .  I have now updated my question, so that it includes the err-msg.

Comment: The column is still a `GENERATED ALWAYS` column though, you **cannot** `UPDATE` such a column.

Comment: It sounds like you misunderstand what temporal tables do. The data to update is the actual customer *data*, not the bookkeeping columns that temporal tables use to handle this data, the idea of temporal tables is to keep track of row changes through some sort of life cycle, so it's easy to see how a row been changing

Comment: Thank you for replies. So there is no way to get around it? I know what these bookeeping columns are and what the whole concept of temporal tables serves for.
But I still need to copy the data from server A to server B. I have wanted to do that using INSERT statements or INSERT+UPDATE statements. But that will change the timestamps, to the date/time of insertion, and it's crucial for my usecase to have the original timestamps.
I will have to look for another technique it seems.

Comment: If you alter the table and drop the `PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME` you can then modify the row start and row end columns before reverting the table back to enable it again. You have to make sure your updates are valid otherwise you won't be able to turn it back on again, but if you are copying from another DB this should not be an issue. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ujfYOQli)

Comment: Can I ALTER the column temporarily to that is not GENERATED ALWAYS, than modify the data, then ALTER it back to GENERATED ALWAYS again?

Comment: i think this article might help https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2017/10/24/implementing-temporal-tables-where-you-have-existing-data/

Comment: @GarethD Thank you very very much. I know that the timestamps need to be precise and End of row one must match start of row 2 etc. 
I will give this one a shot, Thx!

Comment: You should've added that you wanted to copy temporal tables, rather than going into details of your implementation

Comment: Thx everyone once again. The statement that was missing was simply: `ALTER TABLE Customer DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME;` Together with `ALTER TABLE dbo.[Customer] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);` it makes the historic columns writable.
Once data is inserted systemversioning can be turned on again :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it appears the real question is not how to `UPDATE` an `ALWAYS GENERATED` column, but how to migrate data from a temporal table into a *new* temporal table. If you need to copy data from a different (temporal) table to a new one, and retain the history dates, then create the new table(s) *not* as a temporal table and then `ALTER` it to one **after** you `INSERT` all the data. If you start by creating the new table as a temporal table then retaining the Start/End dates isn't possible, as you cannot `INSERT` into, or `UPDATE` the values of your `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns. See the linked duplicate (as this question was closed after this answer was added), on how to completely disable the `GENERATED ALWAYS` feature.

This means you create the table, and history tables, *not* as a temporal table. Such as like below (the `CONSTRAINT`s are **important**):

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
                                  SomeString varchar(10) NULL,
                                  ValidFrom datetime2(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTemporalTable_ValidFrom DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
                                  ValidTo datetime2(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTemporalTable_ValidTo DEFAULT '9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999')
GO
--Assumes existence of a history schema
CREATE TABLE history.MyTemporalTable (ID int NOT NULL,
                                      SomeString varchar(10) NULL,
                                      ValidFrom datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
                                      ValidTo datetime2(7) NOT NULL);
```

Now you `INSERT` all your data into these 2 tables. I'm just going to use some made up data here, it doesn't come from another table:

```sql
DECLARE @SomeArbitraryTime datetime2(7)= SYSDATETIME();

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTemporalTable (SomeString,ValidFrom)
VALUES('abc', DATEADD(DAY, -1, @SomeArbitraryTime)),
      ('def',@SomeArbitraryTime);
INSERT INTO history.MyTemporalTable (ID,
                                     SomeString,
                                     ValidFrom,
                                     ValidTo)
VALUES(2,'xyz',DATEADD(DAY, -1, @SomeArbitraryTime),@SomeArbitraryTime);
```

Now all the data is in the 2 tables, we can make the tables temporal:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom,ValidTo);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = history.MyTemporalTable));
```

And now we can do a couple of queries, and get the expected results:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTemporalTable;

DECLARE @12HoursAgo datetime2(7) = DATEADD(HOUR, -12, SYSDATETIME());

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTemporalTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @12HoursAgo;
```

Which returns the following 2 data sets:

| ID | SomeString | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2024-03-25 12:38:49.1272105 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| 2 | def | 2024-03-26 12:38:49.1272105 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |

| ID | SomeString | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2024-03-25 12:38:49.1272105 | 9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999 |
| 2 | xyz | 2024-03-25 12:38:49.1272105 | 2024-03-26 12:38:49.1272105 |

---

*Clean up:*

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTemporalTable;
DROP TABLE history.MyTemporalTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hhp0Om3n)